# SQL query to delete WP users with duplicate first and last names

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

We have a woocommerce site that has had a backdoor registration for years resulting in thousands of spam accounts.

I've been able to remove all of the ".ru" and other spam email accounts but there are many gmail addresses being used.

The one thing that seems to be common for many of these is that the first and last name are identical ex: "Donaldpat Donaldpat".

How would I write an SQL query that would delete the users from the wp_users table that have an identical value for first and last name in the related wp_usermeta table values?

would it be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_users
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
AND wp_usermeta.first_name = wp_usermeta.last_name
)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What type of sample data should I post? The  desired results are: delete all users from the wp_users table if the values in the wp_usermeta table that match their ID have duplicate values for first & last name.

Comment: Bobby Kennedy would have appreciated this endeavour.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, what I'm doing here is separating the `users.ID` that I don't need so I just have the tables that I want to remove. Instead of using `EXISTS` I decided to use `IN` because that way you get the list ID directly, and remove them.

```
DELETE FROM wp_users
WHERE wp_users.ID IN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
  FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE wp_usermeta.first_name = wp_usermeta.last_name
)
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will test on our development database and let you know.